# losse tummy fat and side fats

Tags: weight-loss

What are the work out for my tummy fats? And do i need to take fat cutter which my trainer insist i should. 
Dont i have any other way to cut my fats and get a "V"  shape body??
I have been doing work outs like for 15 days but i dont see any changes and i am worried about my body. Why am i not seeing any changes? Are the workout not sufficient? Or is it necessary to take fat cutter ?
Please any of you people could give me there whatsaap number so i could talk to some expert people because i am very worried about my body.

Comment: In general it takes as long or longer to lose weight as it did for you to originally gain the weight. 15 days is way too soon to pass judgement on your progress in the beginning. Stay away from fat loss supplements, eating a nutrient rich diet with a sustainable caloric deficit is your best option for losing fat. Also, you cannot spot reduce; you can only reduce your overall body fat which will eventually lead to reduced belly / side fat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no workout of any kind that will reduce fat on your stomach area specifically. Fat is the regulator your body uses to make sure you have enough energy every day, even if you don't eat as much energy as you use. So the only way to lose fat is to eat less than you use, this can be achieved by eating less or by exercising more. That way, a net loss of fat mass will occur.

If by "fat cutter" you mean some kind of supplement, at least where I'm from, there are no legal supplements that will increase fat loss. There are illegal and dangerous supplements that can have a small effect, but you'll still need to have a net calorie deficiency to lose fat.

Also, 15 days is no where near enough time to make any change. The smallest amount of time that can give you any visual change is something like 3 months of intelligent, effortfull exercise and a good diet. By then you'll start seeing some changes.

Comment: At that, many of the supplements which have measurable results in fat reduction do so because they contain stimulants ranging from natural to the companies grinding up medicine and adding it.

Comment: Cant i loose my tummy fats from abs workout?

Comment: No, ab workouts don't use more ab fat than any other fat, running will be a lot more useful.